# Find all integers $a,b,c$ such that $\frac {abc}{a+b+c}$ is an integer.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find all integers $ (a,b,c) $ such that $ \frac{abc}{a+b+c} $ is an integer.

Could someone help me with this number theory problem?

Comment: Have you tried something? Any approach. It will help us posting sufficient answer.

Comment: I want to try solve this problem alone but it's hard for me. I know elements of congurence theory, euler function. I know this is equivalent to something called diophantine equation in form: abc = ka+kb+kc. But I can't find something what can help me solve this

Comment: Maybe approach with polynomials? Something like (x-a)(x-b)(x-c) = x^3-(a+b+c)x^2+(ab+bc+ca)x-abc has (a+b+c) and abc but don't have fraction with this quantities

Comment: Fun fact: $a+b+c\mid a^3+b^3+c^3,$$\, a^5+b^5+c^5,$$\,a^7+b^7+c^7,\,\ldots$, because 

$$a^n+b^n+c^n=\left(a^{n-1}+b^{n-1}+c^{n-1}\right)\left(a+b+c\right)-\left(a^{n-2}+b^{n-2}+c^{n-2}\right)(ab+bc+ca)+\left(a^{n-3}+b^{n-3}+c^{n-3}\right)abc$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Choose $a$ and $b$ randomly and denote $ab=x$ and $a+b=y$ .You want that :
$$c+y \mid cx$$ or equivalently $$c+y \mid xy$$ so just choose some random divisor $d$ of $xy$ and choose $c=d-y$ .So all solutions are the triplets :

$$(a,b,d-a-b)$$ where $d$ is a divisor of $$ab(a+b)$$

Comment: why is first step equivalent? i see only implication in one direction.

Comment: @pablo : Because $$c+y \mid x(c+y)$$ so subtracting them yields : $$c+y \mid x(c+y)-cx=xy$$ as wanted

Answer (score 4):

Note that $$\frac{abt}{a+b+t}=ab-\frac{ab(a+b)}{a+b+t}.$$
So pick any $a,b$ and list the divisors (positive and negative} of $ab(a+b)$ and then solve $a+b+t=d$ for each divisor $d.$